# batch file to create folder and move files not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

So basically what I want to do is

1. select files and folder
2. send to the batch file kept in sendto folder

   3.a. if its a folder then do some jobs (done )

   3.b. if its a files

   I. If the same name folder does not exists then create one

   II. move the file to the folder

I'v wrote following script but it does not work properly, the last if 
condition never runs. What am I doing wrong here and how to solve it?

```
@echo off
:my_loop
    IF [%1]==[] GOTO completed
    if not exist %1"\" (
        set /P "create=Its a file, want to create a folder? Y/[N] "
        if /I "%create%"=="Y" (         rem This loopdoes not run
            mkdir %~n1
            move "%1" "%~n1"
            )
        )
    cd %1
    set /p "clearc=Press any key"
    SHIFT
    GOTO my_loop

:completed
```

Comment: It should read `if not exist "%~1\"`; and replace `if [%1]==[]` by `if "%~1"=="". For variable `create` you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); by the way, for `Y`/`N` prompts, you could use [`choice`](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)...

Comment: Where you are looking for ``%1\`` and where you are making a folder with `mkdir "%~n1"` may be two very different places...

Comment: @aschipfl can check your first two suggestions, because I used those exactly initially but those doesn't work properly, also can you give solutions for the problem I'm facing

Comment: If I jist remove all the mkdir and the move things and put a simple echo there still it does not work, so thats why I think the problem here is with the If condition